# Dynamic array to create multiple Pivot table per value in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic, pivot-table

VBA code to produce one pivot table per date value in `VarPages.array`.

```vb
Sub montage_TCD()

Mise en place du TCD par jour

Dim TCDrange As Range
Dim fin As String
Dim i As Long
Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
Dim objPivotCache As PivotCache
Dim varPages As Variant

Worksheets("Rapportjour").Activate
Columns("A:P").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Set nb_date = Worksheets("Parametre").Range("F2")

Worksheets("Passages").Activate
fin = Cells.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Address

Set TCDrange = Worksheets("Passages").Range("$A$1:" & fin)
varPages = Array("01/04", "03/04", "04/04", "05/04", "06/04", _
"07/04", "08/04", "10/04", "11/04", "12/04", "13/04", "14/04", "16/04", _
"17/04", "18/04", "19/04", "20/04", "21/04", "22/04", "24/04", "25/04", _
"26/04", "27/04", "28/04", "29/04", "30/04", "01/05", "02/05", "03/05", _
"04/05", "05/05", "06/05", "07/05", "08/05", "09/05", "10/05", "11/05", _
"12/05", "13/05", "14/05", "15/05", "16/05", "17/05", "18/05", "19/05", _
"20/05", "22/05", "23/05", "24/05", "25/05", "26/05", "27/05", "29/05", _
"30/05", "31/05", "01/06", "02/06", "03/06", "04/06", "05/06", "06/06", _
"07/06", "08/06", "09/06", "10/06", "12/06", "13/06", "14/06", "15/06", _
"16/06", "17/06", "18/06", "19/06", "20/06", "21/06", "22/06", "23/06", _
"24/06", "26/06", "27/06", "28/06", "29/06", "30/06", "01/07", "03/07", _
"04/07", "05/07", "06/07", "07/07", "08/07", "10/07", "11/07", "12/07", _
"13/07", "14/07", "15/07", "17/07", "18/07", "19/07", "20/07", "21/07", _
"22/07", "23/07", "24/07", "25/07", "26/07", "27/07", "28/07", "29/07", "31/07")
'incruster manuellement les infos de la cellule F7 feuille "parametre" dans array

Worksheets("Rapportjour").Activate
'J'active ma feuille Rapportjour
Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
  SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
  SourceData:=TCDrange)
    
For i = 1 To nb_date
    'Créer le tableau croisé dynamique à partir de la source de base
    
    DernLigne = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set objPivotTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add( _
      PivotCache:=objPivotCache, _
      TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & DernLigne + 4), _
      TableName:="TCD" & i)
    'Ajout des champs pour le tableau croisé dynamique
    
    With objPivotTable
        .AddDataField objPivotTable.PivotFields("PAX"), "Count of PAX", xlSum
        .AddDataField objPivotTable.PivotFields("VHL"), "Count VHL", xlSum
        .AddDataField objPivotTable.PivotFields("Camions"), "Count Camions", xlSum
        .AddDataField objPivotTable.PivotFields("Motos"), "Count motos", xlSum
        .AddDataField objPivotTable.PivotFields("Vélos"), "Count vélos", xlSum
        .PivotFields("Horaire_depart").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Horaire_depart").Caption = "Heures et point départ"
        With .PivotFields("Jour départ")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .CurrentPage = varPages(i - 1)
        End With
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

The problem is my array is dynamic and I must adjust manually the values :

Array("01/04", "03/04", "04/04", "05/04", "06/04", _
"07/04", "08/04", "10/04", "11/04", "12/04", "13/04", "14/04", "16/04", _
"17/04", "18/04", "19/04", "20/04", "21/04", "22/04", "24/04", "25/04", _
"26/04", "27/04", "28/04", "29/04", "30/04", "01/05", "02/05", "03/05", _
"04/05", "05/05", "06/05", "07/05", "08/05", "09/05", "10/05", "11/05", _
"12/05", "13/05", "14/05", "15/05", "16/05", "17/05", "18/05", "19/05", _
"20/05", "22/05", "23/05", "24/05", "25/05", "26/05", "27/05", "29/05", _
"30/05", "31/05", "01/06", "02/06", "03/06", "04/06", "05/06", "06/06", _
"07/06", "08/06", "09/06", "10/06", "12/06", "13/06", "14/06", "15/06", _
"16/06", "17/06", "18/06", "19/06", "20/06", "21/06", "22/06", "23/06", _
"24/06", "26/06", "27/06", "28/06", "29/06", "30/06", "01/07", "03/07", _
"04/07", "05/07", "06/07", "07/07", "08/07", "10/07", "11/07", "12/07", _
"13/07", "14/07", "15/07", "17/07", "18/07", "19/07", "20/07", "21/07", _
"22/07", "23/07", "24/07", "25/07", "26/07", "27/07", "28/07", "29/07", "31/07")

Is it possible to import automatically my array value from a cell value from another Worksheets - i.e: Worksheets("Parametre").Range("F6")?

Comment: You can use the Split function to return a 0-based array of substrings from your cell.  So, for example, `varPages = Split(Worksheets("Parametre").Range("F6").Value, ",")`.

Comment: Domenic thank you for the advice, it just went perfectly well with de Split function.